# how can i get first name & last name of facebook during integration in android studio

Tags: android, facebook

I want to get the first name and last name of FB API, during the implementation of Facebook API in Android studio. I am only getting the full name, please help me

Comment: you can get substring with '.' and take first and last string from array

Comment: using substring is a bad idea, people could have more names.

Answer (score 1):

On Your FaceBook Login Button

set call back Manager Object

```
mCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();



    btn_FBSignUp.registerCallback(mCallbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                   
    //GraphRequest help you get data 
    
                    GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                            loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                            new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                                @Override
                                public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                                    Log.i("LoginActivity", response.toString());
                                    try {
                                        // Application code
                                        String email = response.getJSONObject().getString("email");
                                        String Name = object.getString("first_name");
    
                              
                                        Toast.makeText(RegistrationActivity.this, Name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    } catch (Exception e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();

 //this line will define that what you want to get from 

                    parameters.putString("fields", "id, first_name, last_name,email,gender,birthday"); user porfile...
                    request.setParameters(parameters);
                    request.executeAsync();
    
                }
    
                @Override
                public void onCancel() {
                    // App code
                    Toast.makeText(RegistrationActivity.this, "FaceBook Login is Cancled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
    
                @Override
                public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                    // App code
                    Toast.makeText(RegistrationActivity.this, "Something Happend Wrong: try Again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/me?fields=id,name,first_name,last_name
```

It is called "Declarative Fields", you have to ask for the fields you want to get or you will only get default ones (id, name).

Answer (score 0):

add in your onSuccess callback:

```
override fun onSuccess(result: LoginResult) {
    val request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(result.accessToken) { jsonObject, response ->
        try {
            val firstName = jsonObject?.getString("first_name") ?: ""
            val lastName = jsonObject?.getString("last_name") ?: ""
            val email = jsonObject?.getString("email")

            //handle result here
        } catch (e: JSONException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
    val parameters = Bundle()
    parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email,first_name,last_name")
    request.parameters = parameters
    request.executeAsync()
}
```